# How do you enable Apache to work on IPV4?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

Greetings, I have searched through the similar questions but didn't found an answer. Also I did search on google but nothing relevant that could help me.

I have a desktop with 10.04 ubuntu on it and lamp. The problem is that I want apache to work with IPV4.How do I do that? What exactly do I need to write on my httpd.conf file?

Comment: This is not a question I expected to see for another 5 years or so...

Answer (score 3):

By defaul apache should work on ipv4 protocol. 
check

> /etc/apache2/ports.conf

for host and port configuration.
also check http://localhost to know if apache is working.
if not -- run console and print there

sudo service apache2 start

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna guess that when you access localhost you notice it's running IPv6. This is because /etc/hosts and/or your nameserver points localhost to ::1 and your browser contacts apache this way. Either tell your browser to prefer IPv4 or access 127.0.0.1 through a different hostname which you specify in /etc/hosts or your name server.